# Receive SMS with Plivo/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, plivo

I've been trying to implement a function that retrieve the data from a SMS we send to Plivo. 
Currently in my website, I can send a SMS, check the status, but I want users to be able to respond to these SMS and store these data into my database. I [followed the documentation here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/receive-an-sms/)
I have this controller :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Receive extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('receive_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Sender's phone numer
        $from_number = $this->input->get("From");
        // Receiver's phone number - Plivo number
        $to_number = $this->input->get("To");
        // The SMS text message which was received
        $text = $this->input->get("Text");
        // Output the text which was received to the log file.
        // error_log("Message received - From: ".$from_number.", To: ".$to_number. ", Text: ".$text);
        $arr = array("from" => $from_number, "to" => $to_number, "text" => $text);
        $this->receive_model->add($arr);
    }

}
```

In the example, they use $_REQUEST but it seems that it doesn't work on Codeigniter, so I tried with $this->input->get("From") but no success.
Plivo receives the SMS, it's written Received on Plivo Logs, and I wrote the URL that points to this controller.

Any idea ?

Comment: set `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` in config.php

Comment: It's already on True

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to debug this issue:

1. Check the **Message URL** of the Plivo application if it is set properly with your number.
2. Set **Message Method** as POST. It is relevant to CodeIgniter.
3. Enable CI error log on config/config.php and put the below code into your controller method to log all requests.

> log_message('error', "Plivo Responses: " . print_r($_REQUEST, true)
>   ."\n");

4. Receive a test message (or you can run a simple HTML form by adding SMS fields).
5. Check your CI log.